# match or nearest match of two dataframe datetime columns and read only one column value from second dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, date

I have two csv file -

CSV A-

```
 Timestamp          Date/Time            Error_1            Error_2
170:02:46:928    2023/01/01 16:45:11     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data
170:28:37:328    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration
```

CSV B-

```
 Timestamp          Date/Time            Error_1            Error_2                 Error_3
170:02:46:928    2023/01/01 16:45:07     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR
170:14:40:928    2023/01/01 16:45:10     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               Loss_of_Data 
170:28:16:928    2023/01/01 17:10:44     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR 
170:28:37:328    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration         ERROR 
170:29:57:728    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         PEB_due_to_overlimit       Due_to_Over_SBI 
170:32:59:978    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR 
170:33:40:778    2023/01/01 17:16:08     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR
```

I want to compare CSV-A both Date/Time with CSV-B and read the Error_3 column value if Date/Time match or nearest match. Final output I want something like -

CSV A-

```
 Timestamp          Date/Time            Error_1            Error_2             Error_3
170:02:46:928    2023/01/01 16:45:11     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data           Loss_of_Data
170:28:37:328    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration     ERROR
```

First row from CSV-A Date/Time(2023/01/01 16:45:11) is not matched in CSV-B that's why we checked the nearest match i.e. '2023/01/01 16:45:10' (usually it will be 1 or 2 seconds difference if not exact match).
Second row has three exact match but we need to read the value where CSV-B Error_2='SB_Data_Expiration'.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `parse_dates` for datetimes and then pass to [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with parameter `direction='nearest'` and `tolerance`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, parse_dates=[1])
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, parse_dates=[1])

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2[['Date/Time','Error_3']], 
                   on='Date/Time', 
                   direction='nearest', 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta('3 sec'))
print (df)
       Timestamp           Date/Time  Error_1             Error_2  \
0  170:02:46:928 2023-01-01 16:45:11  APP_ERR        Loss_of_Data   
1  170:28:37:328 2023-01-01 17:11:04  APP_ERR  SB_Data_Expiration   

        Error_3  
0  Loss_of_Data  
1         ERROR
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, thank you for the reply. I found another data file having more than one exact match, how can we put the column value condition to read the specific row ? modified the question also.

Comment: @RKIDEV - Do you need `df2[['Date/Time','Error_3']]` change to `df2[['Date/Time','Error_3']].drop_duplicates()` for match first duplicated values ?

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, yeah we can try but I want to keep the row from duplicates based on      CSV-B Error_2 column value i.e. 'SB_Data_Expiration', sometimes it can be first row, middle row or may be last row.

Comment: @RKIDEV - What is logic here? How dinstinguish if firat, last or middle row?

Comment: @jazrael- Out of three I need to take row where Error_2=‘SB_Data_Expiration’ from CSV_B. And this value will be unique in these 3 filtered row.